# Python regular expression: how to return search value?

Tags: python, regex

I'm sure that this is a very elementary question, so thank you in advance for your patience.

I'm using a simple regular expression to identify whether a year is present in a line of text (line is a dictionary so I'm calling the particular field I want to search). Then I want to do something with the year. My question is, how can I return the year that my search finds? Everything I'm finding online tells me how to replace or edit it, but in this case the value is the thing I want to extract/use.

```
p = re.compile('\d{4}')
if p.search(line['productionStartYear']):
    # do something with the value the regular expression found
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: `re.match()` and `re.group()`. `re.search()` might also be useful. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the matched object in a variable, then use [`group()` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) in order to return the matched string.

```
p = re.compile('\d{4}')
matched_obj = p.search(line['productionStartYear'])
if matched_obj:
    # do something with the value the regular expression found
    # print matched_obj.group(0)
else:
    # do something else
```

> **match.group([group1, ...])**
>
> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned). If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string; if it is in the inclusive range [1..99], it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized group.

Comment: That make sense, could you give an example or comment on the syntax? I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'group' when I try to do what you described. (Doesn't seem I can enter code as a comment)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!